# Moving in-page CSS to external file

Tags: html, css

When I put the CSS below in-line, in the head section of HTML document, everything seems to work fine. However, when I move the CSS to an external file, it does not work as it did when inline.

My question is, when I move the CSS code to an external file, do I need to change anything? Why does it not work in the same way as when it is in the HTML head?

Any suggestion for me? Thanks for all the help...

My menu CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .red #slatenav {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        height:42px;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:bold;
        background:transparent url(MyImages/MenuLine.jpg) repeat-x top left;
        font-family: Calibri;
    }
    .red #slatenav ul {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0;
        list-style-type:none;
        width:auto;
    }
    .red #slatenav ul li {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        margin:0 1px 0 0;
    }
    .red #slatenav ul li a {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:12px 28px 0 28px;
        height:28px;
        border: 1px #606060 solid;
    }
</style>
```

My menu HTML

```
<div class="red">
    <div id="slatenav">
        <ul>
            <li id="Home"><a href="#" title="css menus"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="css menus">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="css menus">Solutions</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="css menus">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="css menus">Technical Support</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3wJfx/

Comment: In the external css, do you omit the style tag?  You may want to post your directory structure and the link tag used to import the stylesheet.

Comment: Have you included a reference to the stylesheet within the HTML?

Comment: link is styles folder and not a problem..thats why working like half manner <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> Thanks again...

Comment: I've created a jsFiddle for you. Follow the link, and then let us know what we should be seeing that we aren't (other than the images, obviously).

Comment: Thanks Tieson to edit my question as very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"it does not work as it did when inline." is a little vague. If this is your only use of CSS, then it should resolve the same. If there are other stylesheets, you have to remember that, given equal specificity, the last rule applied "wins", with inline rules generally being evaluated as most specific.

You also have to remember that URLs, like your image references, will resolve relative to the stylesheet. So, given that you said your stylesheet was in a `Styles` folder, the URL `MyImages/MenuLine.jpg` will resolve as `Styles/MyImages/MenuLine.jpg`.

Comment: MyImages folder only..not in styles folder...I checked with other menus...it's working nice...Only for this menu I get this problem

Comment: No other sheets Tieson...Thanks for your minutes

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was not the case, *but* without either an initial `/` or `../`, `Styles/MyImages/MenuLine.jpg` *is* what the browser will try to request, unless you've specified the base URL using a `<meta />` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>` from your external stylesheet.

**Steps to add external stylesheet.**

1) Add the code `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` within your head tag.

2) Create a file named **style.css** and paste your styles into that file. Keep in mind that you exclude the portions `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>` from your external stylesheet.

3) The style.css and the HTML file should be in the same location.

Comment: No leo...Iam using like that only...but not working like the same sheet head

Comment: @user2715284 I have edited my answer, follow the steps and see its working or not.

Comment: Yes leo, Iam using like that only...but not working like the same sheet head can you please check again?...

Comment: Can you atleast provide your folder structure of the project? and the entire code using for your HTML page?

Comment: Styles folder inside Site.css is available...And MyImages folder inside Image is available.. Thanks Leo...

Comment: Thanks for the advices...Now my monkey mind is accepeted the folder problem...May it might be an issue...Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I hope your style.css is like this

```
.red #slatenav{position:relative;display:block;height:42px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold; background:transparent url(MyImages/MenuLine.jpg) repeat-x top left;font-family: Calibri; }
.red #slatenav ul{margin:0px;padding:0;list-style-type:none;width:auto;}
.red #slatenav ul li{display:block;float:left;margin:0 1px 0 0; }
.red #slatenav ul li a{display:block;float:left;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:12px 28px 0 28px;height:28px;border: 1px #606060 solid;}
```

That is without `<style type="text/css" ></style>` tag and in your HTML, stylesheet will be linked like this `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` (include in head tag)

Comment: Give the link to your page,so that we can examine.

Comment: you mean <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: No,post the link to the webpage. So that we can examine,how you are doing it.

Comment: It's in my system, localhost